# How to share with a remote Windows user?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have Ubuntu One enabled and working on my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop. My partner, at a remote location, uses Windows (XP & 7). I enabled a specific folder for him to access (to view, not change the files). If he downloads the Windows client, what URL does he need to access to view/download the files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you share a folder, he will get an email telling him the correct URL.